# Spartan 6 and flash memory data transferring

Tags: memory, usb-flash-drive

I have an spartan 6 board. I need a flash memory with USB interface(like transcend, Silicon power,... ) to save some data to my board user. I haven't any idea about transfer speed. I need about 13 MByte/s. This is available on windows data transferring to flash memories. Is it available for me on board? What is your offer about interface with flash?(Driver IC or IPCore or Micro controler or ...) and how to make file in flash(.txt, .csv)?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  How you access the onboard memory is well documented by Xilinx.

Comment: This is not a Trainer Board or Eval. Board. This is a custom designed board. So my problem is: How to communicate with USB flash drive(external device) and save my data on it?